# How would variable scope work in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, scope

Hey guys, i ask a similar question earlier and i apologize for kind of double posting, but this is question much more gear towards what i wanted. Ive been spending hours figuring this out and have not come up with much so far.

There are three functions , one overarching function and then two functions within it which are trigger by toggle event. And i want the second function to do something to get a value and pass it on to the second function.

```
   function(){

    $('selector').toggle(

        //i want this to gather a value and store it in a variable
        function(){ },

        //and i want this to accept the variable and value from the previous function
        function(){}
    )}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Data (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store a value for a **each** element in the selector matches to store and retrieve a value.

exa:

```
function(a,b){



     $('selector').toggle(

            //i want this to gather a value and store it in a variable
            function(){ 
             $(this).data("<YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME>", <YOUR_VARIABLE_VALUE>);
            },

            //and i want this to accept the variable and value from the previous function
            function(){
             var someVariable  = $(this).data("<YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME>");
            }
        )}
```

Comment: ok thats the weird part. i used $(this).data() and it used alert() to check if the value was correct. It return the correct value for the first function, but for the second function it returned null. Everything was the same but somehow it returned null for the second function

Comment: Have posted a sample...pls try in those lines and let me know if you still have a problem...

Comment: ok i used alert($(this).data("variable_name")) in both functions again and it return the correct value for the first function, but it returned null for the second function. i did exactly as you said...why  wont this work...

Comment: Can you post the code that you have used? Much better if you can post @ jsfiddle.net

Comment: ok well im speechless, this works in jsfiddle, but im testing it out on my website and it doesnt work...wow... Heres the link btw http://jsfiddle.net/tXLC4/

Answer (score 0):

```
function(){
  // this var will be in scope for anything inside this function
  var availableInBoth;

  $('selector').toggle( function(){
      // this var is only usable in this function
      var availableHereOnly = 10;
      availableInBoth = 10;
  }, function(){
      console.log(availableInBoth);
  })
}
```